# Spring JPA: How to get the custom json response

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I need to list all the permission available in the system, and on each permission i need to show to particular user which permission is active on him ...
here is table relations:
[image]

All Record from Table: authority_master(select * from authority_master)
[image]
All Record from Table: users_authority_relation (select * from users_authority_relation;)
[image]
All Record from Table: userdetails (select*from userdetails)
[image]

**Expected JSON Output :** if i want to know which and all permission active on each user(basically whose record exists in table "user_authority_relation" table ,(here i want to list all the permissions available in table "authority_master" and on that "isActive" json key is True only if that particular authority exists in table "user_authority_relation"

Basically i need to select userdetails table and join with users_authority_relation , this will give result only who has permission But it will not list all the avaialble permission. i am confused on this how to get like below expected json result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i am also in spring boot learning phase and i found your problem interesting so i attempted to solve your problem

Your entity beans might look like this

user_authority_relation bean

```
@Table(name="user_authority_relation")
@Data
public class UserAuthRelation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    Long user_auth_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    UserDetails user;

    @JoinColumn(name="authorityid")
    @OneToOne
    AuthorityMaster authority;
    
}
```

UserDetailsBean.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userdetails")
@Data
public class UserDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long userid;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    List<UserAuthRelation> userAuths;
    
}
```

AuthorityMaster.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="authority_master")
@Data
public class AuthorityMaster implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long authorityid;
    String authority;
    String description;
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AuthorityMaster other = (AuthorityMaster) obj;
        if (authorityid == null) {
            if (other.authorityid != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!authorityid.equals(other.authorityid))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((authorityid == null) ? 0 : authorityid.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    
    
}
```

To get desired response, we need to make some classes which can help to create custom response bean which may look like this

```
@Data
public class CustomResponseJson implements Serializable {

    List<UserResponseJson> usersList;
    
}


@Data
public class UserResponseJson {
    Long userId;
    List<PermissionObject> permissions;
}

@Data
public class PermissionObject {
        String authority;
        Long authorityid;
        Boolean isactive;
}
```

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailRepository userRepo;
    @Autowired
    AuthorityRepository authRepo;
    
    @GetMapping("/fetchUserPermissons")
    @ResponseBody
    public CustomResponseJson fetchUserPermission() {

        //find all available users 
        List<UserDetails> users = userRepo.findAll();

        //find all available authorities
        List<AuthorityMaster> auths = authRepo.findAll();

        //initilizing custom reponse bean
        CustomResponseJson res =new CustomResponseJson();

        if(users!=null && !users.isEmpty()){

            //list of all users in json response
            List<UserResponseJson> userJsonReponse = new ArrayList<UserResponseJson>();

            for(UserDetails user : users){
                UserResponseJson userjson = new UserResponseJson();
                userjson.setUserId(user.getUserid());

                //prepare list of all authority availed and not availed to user
                List<PermissionObject> permissions = new ArrayList<PermissionObject>();
                if(user.getUserAuths()!=null && user.getUserAuths().size()>0){
                    List<AuthorityMaster> tempList = new ArrayList<AuthorityMaster>();
                    for(UserAuthRelation rel : user.getUserAuths()){
                        tempList.add(rel.getAuthority());
                        PermissionObject permObj = new PermissionObject();
                        permObj.setAuthority(rel.getAuthority().getAuthority());
                        permObj.setAuthorityid(rel.getAuthority().getAuthorityid());
                        permObj.setIsactive(true);
                        permissions.add(permObj);
                    }

                    //to find authority which is not assigned to user
                    List<AuthorityMaster> remainedAuths = auths.stream()
                          .filter(e -> !tempList.contains(e))
                          .collect (Collectors.toList());
                    for(AuthorityMaster auth:remainedAuths){
                        PermissionObject permObj = new PermissionObject();
                        permObj.setAuthority(auth.getAuthority());
                        permObj.setAuthorityid(auth.getAuthorityid());
                        permObj.setIsactive(false);
                        permissions.add(permObj);
                    }
                }
                userjson.setPermissions(permissions);
                userJsonReponse.add(userjson);
            }

            res.setUsersList(userJsonReponse);
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to make multiple database call, you can do this

1. Get list of Authority `authList` from database.
2. Get list of users
3. For each user do the step 4-5
4. loop  `authList` and check if the current user's authority list contains the element. if yes set isActive true otherwise false.
5. Set the `authList` as currents users permission

Answer (score 0):

You should create one response DTO which can hold all data from different resources(databases, external services)

My Controller response is:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AxeleStatisticReportDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<EmailLogDTO> emailAndCount = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<IpLogDTO> ipRequestsCount = new ArrayList<>();
}
```